# OpenCV 2.3.1 and OpenNI Kinect

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, kinect

I am new to this technology and I am trying to use OpenCV and OpenNI in my project, but I have no idea where to start after I link all the lib to my Visual C++ Express. Can someone give me some pointers on how to view my Kinect's camera and process returned values. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV has a sample named `kinect_maps.cpp` which demonstrate interactions with Kinect.

Answer (score 2):

- First, take a look in the documentation, is the openni user guide:
  www openni.org/documentation
- Next you can go to "official group" of openni: http://openni-discussions.979934.n3.nabble.com/
- After, install the openNI, this is a good link about how install(on windows):
  http://studentguru.gr/b/vangos/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-successfully-install-kinect-windows-openni-nite.aspx
- When you install openNI, openNI will show you code samples

**Happy code!!**

Answer (score 0):

After Installing OpenNI, use the following link to compile OpenCV with OpenNI.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html

If everything goes well you will be able to compile and run openni_capture.cpp from opencv sample folder.